# Сохранять файлы из <input type='file'/> в папку "assets" в самом проекте/React

Tags: reactjs

Задача:

В `<input type="file"/>` пользователь будет загружать картинки, в папке проекта есть отдельная папка "assets", в эту папку нужно сохранять эти самые картинки в исходном формате и получать их путь, что бы в дальнейшем создавать объект:

```
const obj = {
    id: 1,
    goodId: 1,
    name: 'image1',
    url: './assets/image.jpeg'
}
```

и постить этот объект в симулятор БД json server.

После в карточке товара получать картинки по ключу "goodId" и выводить их как картинки товара.

Вопрос: Как реализовать сохранение изображений в папку с проектом?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вопрос: Как реализовать сохранение изображений в папку с проектом?

Comment: Для выполнения сохранения файлов, а так же записи информации в БД, вам потребуется серверная часть. На вопрос "Как", можно будет ответить, только поняв, на чем вы будете реализовывать бэковую часть.